# How can I detect the cause of silent failures on Android?

Tags: android, exception, crash, silent

I am debugging an Android application and one of the activities just failed silently; it popped off the back stack and I got the previous activity.

I've seen silent failures of this type that can be attributed to memory problems, but in this case I am testing without the debugger attached.  The logcat shows virtually no information: after some output from our touch listeners, I get

```
I/DEBUG(85): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
I/DEBUG(24919): debuggerd: Jul  8 2011 06:16:01
I/ActivityManager(157): Process com.tse.newsreader (pid 24415) has died.
I/WindowManager(157): WIN DEATH: Window{4108f938 com.tse.newsreader/com.tse.newsreader.activities.StorefrontFragmentActivity paused=false}
```

`com.tse.newsreader` is our process.

I would like to know if this is caused by a memory leak somewhere and I was hoping to add an HPROF dump to a global exception handler, somewhat as described in [Is there a way to take a memory dump on app crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858767/is-there-a-way-to-take-a-memory-dump-on-app-crash) but if there is no exception or `OutOfMemoryError` to catch, I don't see how that will help.

Can anyone suggest how I can get at the cause of these silent failures?

Comment: By the way, the behaviour as the machine failed was: a touch event handler started receiving motion events only in the Y axis (the device was in landscape) and then the window disappeared completely.  I don't know if that is significant.  Our code handles x and y motion events simultaneously, though, so I think this might be a symptom of the underlying cause.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the user can force memory to clear.

Comment: How do you mean?  In this case I was just running the application normally, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you could consider adding something like [bugsense](http://www.bugsense.com/) to your app. It will pick up uncaught exceptions.

Comment: @AndrewWyld Did this help Andrew? As I have the same problem, activity just disapearing without any exception apparently.

Comment: Actually the project got suspended so I haven't had a chance to find out yet!  Sorry :(